# The proper Python exception to break out of an infinite loop (that shouldnt be infinite)

Tags: python, loops, exception

Here's my simplified code:

```
x = 0
while True:
    x += 1
    if not do_stuff(x)
        break
    if x > 1000000:
        raise Exception("Too many iterations")
```

1000000 is a value for `x` that should never be reached. If it is, something has gone wrong and an exception is raised. What would be the proper subclass of `Exception` for such a use case, if any exists at all?

Comment: Something has gone wrong with what? The input, or the program logic? In other words: is it due to an error by the end user, or by the programmer?

Comment: Out sounds like a case for raising `AssertionError`, or inheriting from `RuntimeException` and raising that.

Comment: in my case, do_stuff is opening a web page, but I wondered if there is a general exception for loops that are out of control. (So a programmer mistake)

Comment: There's no builtin exception.  Just derive one from Exception.

Comment: What I wrote in the end is simply `assert x < 1000000`

Comment: so nothing better than `RuntimeException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way this wouldn't occur is if do_stuff never returns false.

If that is the case create a custom exception.
I usually create a MiscException (along with more specific exceptions)

Comment: The benefit of creating and catching a custom exception is that you have no chance of accidentally catching other, more crucial exceptions.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question, "What would be the proper subclass of Exception for such a use case". The answer is either a built in exception type or that there is no such exception type. Please update the answer to explicitly state this information.

Comment: @Rafe Why must the answer be either a built-in type, or that there is no such type?  I think defining a custom class is overkill for quick diagnosis, but it seems like a valid answer to the narrowly asked question.

Comment: @Rafe, ah, perhaps you don't understand that "create a custom exception" involves deriving a class from Exception? That is, making a new subclass of Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an exception at all if you don't want:

```
for i in xrange(1000000):
    if not do_stuff(x):
        break
else:
    # too many iterations, do something else.
```

The for/else construct is a bit exotic, but is just right for this use case.  The else clause is executed if the loop is never broken out of.  It's explained more here: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201110/forelse.html

If you want to use an exception for quick diagnosis, then don't overthink the class to use. Exception is fine.  If you are concerned that something might catch your exception, then use a ZeroDivisionError, which is easy to raise:

```
if x > 1000000:
    1/0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but the point is to raise an exception for quick diagnosis.

Comment: @ToonAlfrink OK, you can raise the exception from the else clause.  It's still a more compact form than a while loop with an incrementing variable.

Comment: Down-voted. This should be a comment, not an answer. The question is valid. Please don't comment on the code pattern used to illustrate the question. Question is, "What would be the proper subclass of Exception for such a use case".

Comment: @Rafe, I've added to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same question. I was not able to find anything built in to python for this. IPython uses `RuntimeError('maximum recursion depth exceeded')`.

Comment: `RuntimeError` *is a built-in exception*.

Comment: RuntimeError is a broad exception. The implicit point of the question was to ask about a specific exception.